# 'Identifying destinations that meet certain criteria is not the same thing as constructing a travel itinerary.'

Tags: discussion

[User phoog commented](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/148863/where-is-a-celebration-free-little-to-no-christmas-skiing-destination-during-th#comment368984_148863), and was upvoted 20 times by others:

> [image]

I'm uncertain then why my questions below were closed? They pertain to identifying destinations that meet certain criteria.

#### Deleted

[Does Japan have resort towns like Banff and Jasper?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/141673/13759)

> My grandparents are planning to travel to [Osaka](https://www.weatherbase.com/compare.php3?first=17774&second=995097) and [Tokyo](https://www.weatherbase.com/compare.php3?first=17674&second=995097)  in Feb. 2020, as they're a touch warmer than Toronto where they live.
>
> Grandma likes shopping and urbanity, but  Grandpa prefers nature and scenery. Has Japan anything like Banff and Jasper (that he loves), with singular admixtures of mountains, water bodies, and laid-back small-town vibes?

#### Open

[Seaside destinations in Japan for nature and scenery?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/31199/13759)
[Within 300 km of Tokyo: Where for flora, landscape, nature?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/31143/13759)
[Any free destinations for nature and flora in Western and Southwestern Ontario?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52548/13759)
[What lookouts or peaks in Charlevoix can I access by rental car?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/141118/13759)
[Which mountains in the Lower Mainland, BC can be ascended by private car in the summer?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76210/13759)
[Are there popular but poorly paved roads on Big Island which require an SUV?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/125554/13759)

Comment: You realise that the only reason it was possible for this question to be reopened is that was initially been closed, right? And you have enough rep to see that there are multiple votes to close it again.

Answer (score 2):

I originally voted to close this question, so I fully agree. While the question is relatively narrow, it still has many possible opinion-based answers, which means its a bad fit for Travel.SE. OP could split the question into several sub-questions, all of which are going to be on-topic:

- How can I find out if a given destination will be busy during Christmas?
- How can I locate ski resorts that are unlikely to have big crowds?
- How can I find the cheapest flight+train/bus+hotel packages from a given city?
- How do I check what holidays are celebrated in a given location, to avoid the busy season?

I won't vote to close again so that the community can decide, but personally I think it should be closed.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't your hypothetical question in your 2nd bullet like mine that were closed?

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal you are asking for specific locations. My questions are asking *how* one can find such locations. Teach a man how to fish vs. giving him fish :)